# Failure on GetVoices more than two

Tags: python-3.7

I'm a novice in programming and can't understand the followings.

Four voices are installed on my PC (Windows10, 64bits).

It went well with "balcon ( Balabolka command line tool )" as follows.

> > balcon -l
>
> ```
> SAPI 5:
>
>   Microsoft Haruka Desktop
>
>   Microsoft Zira Desktop
>
>   ScanSoft Emily_Dri40_16kHz
>
>   ScanSoft Steffi_Dri40_16kHz
>
> >
> ```

But it failed with Python as the followings.

```
> python
Pyhton3.7.2 on win32
>>>import win32com.client
>>>sp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Sapi.SpVoice')
>>>sp.GetVoices().Item(0).GetDescription()
'Microsoft Haruka Desktop - Japanese'
>>>sp.GetVoices().Item(1).GetDescription()
'Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)'
>>>sp.GetVoices().Item(2).GetDescription()
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Item
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception 
occured.', 
(0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352567), None)
>>>
```

Does anyone know in detail about what happened?

Please advise me about how we can get all voices description.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share you code snippet as well please?

Answer (score 0):

Everyone,
Thank you for your interest.

After I put my question, I tried to use Python3.7.2 (32bits version) instead 
of python3.7.2 (64bits version) and then it went pretty well on my PC (Windows
10, 64bits)

I guess python win32com library may work with python3.7.2 (32bits version)
currently.

Thanks again.

Ruri Ob
Kyoto/Yokohama, Japan